# SSRS Report ask for Credentials

Tags: reporting-services

I have report set up at reporting server. And from mvc.net through javascript. I am opening report using the code below:

```
function ShowSnapShot() {
    window.open("http://ServerName/ReportingServerName/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fFolderName%2fSubFolderName%2fReportName&rs:Command=Render&Parameter=003532");    
}
```

Whenever I open the report it asks for credentials. How could I pass Credentials with the url or is there any way I could open the report without using Report Viewer?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the user who is opening this report has *Browse* permissions to the report/folder on the report server.

Additionally, check the credentials on the Data Source used by the report.  You may need to select *Credentials stored securely in the report server*.